# Returning List<T> with WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I got an `Employee` class and each employee has a list of applied leaves. Is it possible to have the list `AppliedLeave` as a `[DataMember]` in WCF?

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmployeeUserID")]
    [DataMember]
    public List<Leave> AppliedLeave
    {
        get { return _appliedLeaves; }
        set { _appliedLeaves = value; }
    }

    private List<Leave> _appliedLeaves = new List<Leave>();
    ...
 }
```

Is there any other way to do this?

thank you for your consideration of this matter

**I extend my Question**

This is my Leave Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Leave
{

    [Key()]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid LeaveId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LeaveType { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EmployeeUserID { get; set; }

}
```

this shows ServiceContract ---->

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEmployeeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Employee GetEmployeeByUserId(string userId);

    [OperationContract]
    void AssignSupervisor(string userId, string supervisorUserId);

    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteEmployeeByUserId(string userId);

....
}
```

In Client application,

> EmployeeServiceClient employeeService = new EmployeeServiceClient();
>
> Employee employee = employeeService.GetEmployeeByUserId(id);

But when Employee gathered from the service its shows Null for leaves,

[image]

Can somebody help me? what have I done wrong here?

Comment: Is the `Leave` class also marked as a `[DataContract]` and its properties as `[DataMember]` ? If so - yes, this should absolutely work.

Comment: Yes marc, I have marked Leave class as [DataContract] and members as [DataMember].but when I work with service other data members can return but not Leave items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to return generics from WCF service operations.

But by default they are casted to Array on client side. This can be customized while proxy generation.

[WCF: Serialization and Generics](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)

Also you have to decorate the service with  all the types to which generics can be resolved, using KnownTypeAttribute.

[Known Types and the Generic Resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

Comment: No, that won't help - quite the contrary. WCF is a **message passing** system and as such, the data going from client to server must be **concrete types** (not interfaces etc.)

Comment: Also it is recommended to use interfaces for collection-members of models instead of concrete types. And in WCF is OK to use interfaces for collections. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx

Comment: Thanks 6opuc, I tried with Interfaces but still doesn't work it

Answer (score 2):

[image: Changes in my Solution]

I also found my server side list would always arrive at the client as a null pointer. After browsing around a lot for this problem it strikes me it is nearly always denied at first ("your code should work")

Found the issue.. I had configured my solution using one "WCF Service" project and one "Winforms app" project with a generated service reference. Both interface and implementation of Service1 were in the WCF service project, as expected. But any list member returned null.

When I put my IService1.cs = the interface *only* = in a separate class library instead, reference the class library on both sides (using) and generate the service reference again, my list does work ! The generated code on the client side looks much simpler.

I did not need any special attributes, change service reference configuration, or interface references for this.